# Is this a reasonable way to construct the syntax node of an abstract syntax tree in C++ (or is there a safer or more memory-efficient construction)?

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a (most likely bottom-up) parser for a new general-purpose programming language. My parser takes in a stream of tokens. For completeness, here is the `token_t`.

```
struct token_t {
    // Kind of token enum
    token_kind kind;
    // Overall position in file
    int position;
    // The location of the token's first associated char (left-to-right, top-to-bottom)
    // Useful for giving feedback if there is a syntax error
    int row, col;
    // The substring associated with the token
    std::string value;
};
```

The syntax nodes are composed of the following:

```
struct syntax_node_t {
    // Kind of syntax node enum (what this node represents, i.e. binary expression)
    syntax_node_kind kind;
    // Token associated with this syntax node
    token_t token;
    // A list of children associated with this kind of syntax node
    std::vector<syntax_node_t> children;
};
```

I would like the parser to store a pointer to the root of the tree (which is a `syntax_node_t`) as it is constructing and when it's done with the abstract syntax tree.

I have one concern and that is that the children vector should be a vector of pointers to `syntax_node_t`, so that the children vector just has references to the nodes instead of copies of them. Is this concern valid, should I change the type to pointers?

Any other feedback is welcome as well.

Comment: No, this is fine. The reason they're called syntax *trees* is because every node only has one owner, so a `std::vector<syntax_node_t>` is fine.

Comment: Some other remarks: if you load the entire source file/input into memory you can replace `value` and `position` with a single `std::string_view` or `std::span`. But don't worry about premature optimization just yet: computers are fast and parsing is the least important bit of any programming language implementation.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, the [kaleidoscope](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/docs/tutorial/LangImpl01.html) programming language front-end (*toy tutorial language*) for LLVM could be of interest.  Or the highly regarded [Compilers](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321486811) "dragon book" by Aho, Ullman, Sethi, & Lam may be of interest.

Comment: I'd second @Botje 's proposal to replace value/position (if his preposition holds). It's not (only) a question of optimisation, but of reasonable choice of types. In general I'd re-think the choice of int for position/row/col : would negative values really be meaningful here? Would it make more sense to have them unsigned?

Comment: This approach will be fine as long as you don't store pointers to your tree nodes elsewhere, i.e. parent pointers, which may be helpful in semantic analysis. Then you stable addresses which you can have by using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<syntax_node_t>>`.